# R package unmarked gdistsamp distsamp pcount

Tags: r, unmarked-package

I am relatively new to R. I conducted repeated 10 min point counts over one season. I have 50 sites (100 m radius) replicated over 3 surveys, and each individual observation (n = 1108) is recorded at discrete distance intervals (i.e., the number of observations for each site during each survey is not always equal). Habitat variables were measured once for each site (n = 50), and detection covariates were measured for each site on each survey (n = 150).

I wish to test the effect(s) of various habitat metrics on songbird abundance/density, to include detection covariate(s) in my models, and to account for repeated measures in my design. I think that 'distsamp' is most appropriate for this, but am not sure (especially when it comes to how to deal with repeated measures).

I have followed Chandler's 'Distance sampling analysis in unmarked (2011)' and everything seems to work until I add detection covariates (using distsamp; prior to adding abundance/density habitat predictors), when running my models produce the warning: "In lambda * A : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

(a) Am I using the appropriate fitting function (i.e., distsamp vs. gdistsamp vs. pcount vs. ???) 
(b) Why am I getting this warning message?

Here is my code:

`dists <-read.csv("file/path.csv")`

## sub-set of variables (to be used as detection covariates)

`jdate<-(dists$day.julian)`
`daytime<-(dists$time.hour.num)`

```
head(dists, 1108)
```

## 'point' contains character+numerical site names (e.g., 'sweco03')

```
levels(dists$point) <- c(levels(dists$point), "sweco03") 
levels(dists$point)
```

## individual observations were recorded at 10 m distance intervals to 100 m

```
umf <-unmarkedFrameDS(y = as.matrix(yDat), survey = "point", dist.breaks =   c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), unitsIn = "m")
```

`summary(umf)`

## to determine the best detection function

```
`hn_Null <- distsamp (~1 ~1, umf, keyfun = "halfnorm", output = "density", unitsOut = "ha") 
haz_Null <-distsamp (~1 ~1, umf, keyfun = "hazard")                #lowest AIC 
uni_Null <- distsamp (~1 ~1, umf, keyfun = "uniform") 
exp_Null <- distsamp (~1 ~1, umf, keyfun = "exp") `
```

## to test the fit of detection covariates

```
model1 <-distsamp (~1 ~jdate, umf, keyfun = "hazard")
model2 <-distsamp (~1 ~daytime, umf, keyfun = "hazard")
```

## etc. When I attempt to run these models, I get the warning message.

Comment: Please improve the title to your question. It's not desirable to list your tags in the title. => http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles